# Substance Look and Feel Applet alert during startup

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet

recently I have discovered substance. When i try to load it in my java program (not applet!) I get errors during startup.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceGraphiteAquaLookAndFeel());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

And those are the errors (Note: Those are pop ups, where --message-- is the title, and {name} are buttons):

- --APPLET ALERT-- The applet is attempting to connect to jar: [...]/substance-6.0/org/pushingpixel/substance/api/skin/graphite.colorschemes. {Allow} {Disallow} {Stop Applet}
- --APPLET ALERT-- The applet is attempting to invoke the java/lang/System.getenv() operatoin on KDE_FULL_SESSION {Allow} {Disallow} {Stop Applet}

The last message appears 5 times whilst writing the following into stderr

```
-->> returning Frame NULL
BaseDialog: owner frame is a java.awt.Frame
```

Also my first window will be loaded with the default swing ui.
After closing this and opening a new one (programmatically) the ui will be initialized.

Is there any way I can bypass the error?

Edit: I use the following libraries: laf-plugin-7.2; laf-widget-7.0; substance-6.0

Comment: Have you signed these jars?

Comment: BaseDialog: owner frame is a java.awt.Frame == maybe this is true, nobody knows,

Comment: No i have not signed those jars. I honestly didnt heard of signing a jar and I dont know what this does. I will take a look into it tomorrow again to see if this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded a fork from: https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/downloads

The other one was not signed because i compiled it myself.